# What is the difference between Lost Technica 《秘奥義【ロスト・テクニカ】》 and Last Crest 《魔道極法【ラスト・クレスト】》?

Tags: trinity-seven

The terms Lost Technica 《秘奥義【ロスト・テクニカ】》 and Last Crest 《魔道極法【ラスト・クレスト】》 are quite ambiguous, since they are usually mentioned together with the explanation for being a member of Trinity Seven.

In chapter 17, both terms are used one after another near the end of the chapter. This is from just before Liese activated her trump card.

> ["To be a Trinity Seven means that you've acquired the *Lost Technica* in your particular archive."  - Liese](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kcMz.png) <sup>[[Japanese version]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRCBi.png)</sup>

When Liese activated her trump card, and Sora (the human form of Astil grimoire), warned Arata about the magic being used.

> ["This is Avaritia's *Lost Technica*, the *Last Crest* ..." - Sora](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzG1X.png)
>
> "That's right. It's ***Baal Peor***" - Liese

Then in chapter 19, the condition to be part of Trinity Seven is reiterated, but this time with *Last Crest* in place of *Lost Technica*:

> "The Trinity Seven are the top class magi of each of the seven deadly sins, right?" - Arata
>
> ["Correct. We are the ones who have mastered the *Last Crest* of each archive" - Lilith](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3fTz.png) <sup>[[Japanese version]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UVNE.png)</sup>

I have two questions regarding these two ambiguous terms:

1. What is the difference between them?
2. Regardless whether they refer to different concept or not, does *Lost Technica* implies *Last Crest* and vice versa?

(Please back up your answer with primary sources, rather than secondary sources like Wikipedia or Wikia. You can use them as starting point, though).